Unable to Add Product to Cart Without Selecting Installment Plan - Magento 2 Issue
Hello Magento Community,
I am facing an issue in Magento 2 where a product cannot be added to the cart unless an installment plan is selected. If I try to add the product without selecting an installment option, I receive an error message saying, "This is a required field.
i also checked that the required button is also set to "NO" eventhough i couldn't able to add product.


What is "Installment plans"? A custom option or a configurable option (product is configurable) ?

This Installment plan option is related to any third party model like partial payment or other custom option?
